# send and receive image using flask-restful (python API) and C# client

Tags: c#, python, xamarin, cross-platform, flask-restful

I am trying to send image to python code from Xamarin forms (cross platform), I'm using flask-restful (python API) to build web server and call it from the Xamarin app , so first I converted image to base 64:

```
 Image2.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
         base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

and the post code in xamarin:

```
var imageContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
            { new StringContent(base64), "ImageData" }
            };
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var imageResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:52524/", imageContent);

            //
            var resultImageContent = imageResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (resultImageContent != null)
            {
                //some code here
            }
```

now how I can receive the image from the python code.

Comment: localhost is not what you think it is, unless your restful API is running on the device.

Comment: it's already running on the device  @Cheesebaron